# How do I deselect one object between other objects?

Tags: objects, select

I often have a problem with deselecting objects in the scene, for this I use the shift+leftclick key. For example, I have two objects selected, and below them a third object, I try to deselect one of the objects,but instead it attaches to them a third object, which is located below them.

Screenshots are attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've already read this question, it should not do that, there must be an option enabled somewhere...

Comment: I`m load factory preferences and load factory settings, but this problem does not disappear.

Comment: Shift+Alt+Click brings a selection menu that can select/deselect objects in selection conflict.

Answer (score 4):

Surely this will not be so easy if many objects are in selection conflict, but, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd> (the click button here may depend on your configuration), brings a menu that allows to choose the wanted object:

[image]

PS: was in hope the object order in the menu was relative to the ray cast distance, but this is not the case.

Comment: Yes it works, but you understand that it is wrong, you do three steps to do what you want, And imagine that you need to do this with several objects. I'm not talking about the fact that you need to track the name of the object and it will be problematic with a lot of selected objects. In any case, thank you, I hope that in the future, developers will make a more standard tool of choice.

Answer (score 1):

For this you should deselect your object in the outliner. The deselect option is in the right click menu. And give your objects other names than e.g Cube006 to make it faster. Another way is to hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and 2× right click on the object.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not help me very much, I have shift+right mouse moves the 3D cursor, and to look for an object in the outliner when these objects are many, it is quite inconvenient, especially to rename them specifically for this. This should be an easy way, as in 90% of other 3D editors, it is strange that the blender pays so much attention to other areas, but did not implement an easy way to remove the selection in such cases.

Comment: @ВладимирТим: give names **upon creation** of course as later it's not much use.